# jquery mobile touch input box to change background color

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile and i want to change the background color of the input box only when the input box is touched and when the user type the text i want to remove the background color .so far i have done this

```
<input type ="text" id="name" placeholder="type">
```

js

```
$("#name").click( function(event) {
         $(this).addClass('tap-button');
    });
```

css

```
.tap-button{
    background:red;}
```

but the background color doesnt goes when typing the text.
any suggestions?

Comment: share ur example demo

Comment: i have added all the codes.

Comment: You can call keypress event and change the color of the text box....

Comment: `$("#name").click( function(event) { $(this).closest('div').addClass('tap-button'); });` add the class to the parent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use touch event

```css
.tap-button{
  background: #004433 !important;
}
```

for jquery use touchevent

```js
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function () {
  $('#name').on('touchstart', function () {
    $(this).addClass('tap-button');
  });
  $("#name").on('touchend', function (event) {
    $(this).removeClass('tap-button');
  });
});
```

[Update demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pzerb/)

Comment: First of all, `.ready()` should never used with jQuery Mobile. Secondly, use `.on` instead of `.bind` as you're dealing with dynamic elements in DOM. Thirdly, it'll partially change the color of the input. Test my demo on your mobile.

Answer (score 3):

To manipulate jQuery Mobile sytles correctly, you need to understand how JQM renders/enhances HTML markup once inserted into DOM.

To change the background color of the `input`, you need to add your style to its' parent `div` using `closest`. That `div` is added by JQM after enhancing the code.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/GQ2Am/)**

```
$('#name').on('click', function () {
 $(this).closest('div').addClass('tap-button');
 $(this).on('keypress', function () {
  $(this).closest('div').removeClass('tap-button');
 });
});
```

This is how jQuery Mobile renders an `input`:

```
<div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-c">
 <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="type" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c">
</div>
```